# URL Redirection in IIS 8.0

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, iis-8

I have hosted my asp.net application on IIS 8.0 server and I am getting it by hitting browser- http://iaccount.example.com/iB/

But I want to get it by hitting only- http://iaccount.example.com/
By the way, right now I am getting IIS default page when hitting http://iaccount.example.com/

How to achieve this? I am very new in application deployment :(

Note: Given URL is for example only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `http://iaccount.example.com/iB/` means that you have setup your application as a sub-application under `Default Website`. You need to setup a new website in IIS, bind your domain name to that website and then map it your published physical directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved already, thanks.

I just added a new application and gave host name as iaccount.example.com, It works for me.